# In a Lotus Notes application, double clicking the document does not changes it into edit mode?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

I have a lotus notes form which does not has any script written in the `QueryModeChange` or `PostModeChange` sections, but, for some of the documents based on this form, when I try to edit the document I am not able to do so.

However, when I copy the same record(from production database) to another copy of the database(stage environment), I am able to edit it. I checked the document and it is not locked with any user.

There is a scheduled agent which has failed on few similar records stating the issue as follows:

```
Error #4000: "Notes error: Field is too large (32K) or View's column & selection formulas are too large"
```

I am not sure if its the same issue, but, I tried the same resolution(that is copying it to another copy of the database) and it worked.

Can some one please help me with the issue?

Comment: Does the document have a field of type "Authors" and current user is not included there and has user Author access only in ACL?

Comment: No, there are no author fields on the form.

Comment: It's not always sufficient to just look at the form. You really have to look at the actual documents and check every item in the scrolling box of fields to see whether there are any that have the flags SUMMARY READ-WRITE ACCESS NAMES. The behavior you are describing is exactly what one would expect if a user copied a document with READ-WRITE ACCESS protection from a database where the user has Author privileges into a database with an ACL that grants the user Editor privileges or above.

Comment: (Clarification: I was referring to the scrollinb box of fields in the document properties dialog box.)

Comment: With regard to the 32K limit issue, can you determine if that affecting the same set of documents?

Comment: I don't think its an access issue, as I have same access to both the copies of the databases and also, when I copy the record (after I have checked that I am able to edit it in stage environment) back to production, I am able to edit it there as well.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I agree with Richard: not being able to edit a document usually has to do with missing rights. What is you access level to the productive database?

But regarding the 32k issue: there are two ways, tat can make this happen.

First it is possible that an item in the document really has more than 32k of data.

BUT: then it would not be possible to edit this document in ANY database you copy it to, as this defective item prohibits opening in any case.

Second possibility is, that the result of a DBLookup/DbColumn in a field (either a computed field, or the list of values for a dropdown or something like that) has grown beyond the 32k border. As soon as you try to edit the document, the field would be recalculated and causes editing to fail.

The error would be the same, if the agent tries to do a doc.ComputeWithForm...

I would check alle dblookups / dbcolumns in the form and check, if one of them got to large...

Comment: I wrote an export to extract the field name and the length of values in it, the maximum length i got was around 6K characters

Comment: This just verifies my statement above: "...then it would not be possible to edit... in another database...".. It means: The item >32k is not currently stored in the document, but is a calculated field, that "overflows" when recalculating the document...

Comment: oh ok, got it, will write a code to blank out the data items one by one and after each item is blanked out will try to save the record, if it doesn't throws any error, then the field which we blanked out just now should be the culprit... thanks, pls, do let me know if you prefer some other way to check this.

Comment: No, this will NOT help, as the items in the document are NOT the problem... But of course you could try... Imho the only way would be to rename the original form and create a new blank one with the same name. Just copy over one field. If it goes to editmode, then copy some more fields from the original form... If it still goes to edit mode, take the next fields, and so on...

Comment: It seems the document's overall summary data was more than 64K and that was causing the issue, I tried blanking out few of the fields which was not needed and it worked.

Comment: Sorry, the description of the issue was incomplete, though the document was editable in the stage database, but, when I tried updating the data, it threw the 32K error.